# Data from excel (open/running) to pandas datatframe

Tags: pandas, excel

Multiple instances of excel are running/open in the background (not focused). Some are running macros and getting data from websites and processing/calculations. How to get data every minute from one of the excel (getting data using DDE) into pandas df without closing and saving the excel ?